# How do you hide that floating scroll indicator thing on mobile?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

At first I thought you could use this rule which works for desktop Chrome:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none
}
```

But it didn’t work. After messing with `webkit-scrollbar` and its other selectors, I realized that this thing might not be part of the `webkit-scrollbar` after all:

[image: The gray scroll bar that appears when scrolling on mobile]

That’s why it’s not affected to whatever rules I make for `webkit-scrollbar`.

That floating scroll indicator thing only appears when you scroll a page.

For context, I’m trying to hide that thing for a website I’m using for reading webtoons because it’s distracting. I’m using the Stylus extension on Kiwi browser (an Android browser based on Chrome that supports extensions) to customize the CSS of a website.

Edit:

These are screenshots of Google search results for "Reddit". `::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}` is on effect. I took them while scrolling. The working scrollbar is visible on desktop but not on mobile. The mobile only has that indicator element thing.

- [Regular - the scrollbar is hidden.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wzhy.png)
- [Device Mode - that indicator thing shows up when you scroll.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98lCJ.png)

Comment: You're not looking for `overflow: hidden`, right?

Comment: @MrLister I'm not 100% sure but doesn' that disallow scrolling? I think I've tried that before and it didn't allow me scrolling so that indicator thing didn't appear as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because Kiwi is based on WebKit, it should be possible. You could try with `width`:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 0 !important 
}
```

Comment: Someone on Reddit said this:


I have no idea what it's actually called, but it does not behave like a scroll bar, in the sense that it doesn't respond to `::-webkit-scrollbar`.

Unfortunately it is part of the operating system, not the browser, and so can not be changed. Basically the browsers have no scrollbar on phones, so they just use the operating system native one, that is why if you install Chrome on iOS you see a totally different scrollbar.

Comment: So, basically, you can't control that.